# httperf hangs when using --hog

Tags: linux, ubuntu, performance-tuning, http-error-401.2, httperf

I'm using httperf from a large ec2 instance with ubuntu 10.04 (no other software installed).

When I test without --hog the tests run however when I use --hog the tests never end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in httperf. found the patch to solve it here:

http://code.google.com/p/httperf/issues/attachmentText?id=15&aid=150000000&name=httperf-0.9.0-hogfix.patch&token=6d1c86ff869b68ec6b06b51adee5f853

Comment: applying this patch to 0.9.0 source worked for me on ec2, ubuntu11.10.  tcp_tw_reuse & recycle did not make a difference.  Linux ip-10-7-203-83 3.0.0-14-virtual #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 21:09:11 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: patch applies on current 0.9.1 svn code as well, applying from line 901.  Unpatched 0.9.1-svn did not work.  Patched 0.9.1-svn did work.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but the patch provided in Niro's answer didn't solve the issue for me.  The issue ended up being TCP connection reuse and recycling.  To fix this I followed instructions found on:
http://www.speedguide.net/articles/linux-tweaking-121

The relevant instructions were to run the following commands:

- echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle
- echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse

Answer (score -2):

strace httperf which is hunging:
mass output
bind(1006, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(58815), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = -1 EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

apply 
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
so,can set big num-conns and rate..,and not hung.

thanks